How do I migrate from Mockito 1 to Mockito 5
I have a build process which uses Gradle 7 for an application currently implemented in Java 8. It uses Mockito 1 to test the Java code in the application. Mockito is supplied to the build process by making mockito-all-1.10.19.jar avaiable in CLASSPATH.
I need to update to Java 17. This requires a newer Mockito as the mechanism for reflection in Java is changed between Java 8 and Java 17. I am trying Mockito 5. Mockito is packaged differently at this level; building from source gives me mockito-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, which doesn't include its prereqs.
I can't figure what to specify to use Mockito 5.
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core?smo=true indicates that I should specify
implementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.11.0'
to Gradle, but when I put this in my Gradle source file I get a Gradle error
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [{group=org.mockito, name=mockito-core, version=5.11.0}] on root project 'Java' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I also tried
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.11.0'
}

but that didn't work either. This gives
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [{group=org.mockito, name=mockito-core, version=5.11.0}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.


I have edited the question to put in what happened when I tried the dependencies { } version.

Do you use the groovy (build.gradle) or kotlin (build.gradle.kts) DSL?

Sorry for my first reaction. I missed the fact that you had posted the error message.

You need to explain what artifact repository you intend to use in your build. Do you have one in the company? Do you intend to use maven central? Have you added them to repositories in your gradle build? Also, you mention building Mockito from source - this is a completely different approach than importing it from some repository - and not a common one.
